# Shopify activate account email

Tags: c#, shopify, shopify-app

Is there a way to specify URL for the "activate account" button? I would like the link to point to my own custom storefront.

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/customers/customer#account_activation_url

their api does not list any type of URL redirect option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off by letting Shopify handle the account activation as normal, while you, clever of all clever ones, have your little secure private App waiting in the background to deal with this.

You listen for customer updates which Shopify will send your endpoint URL whenever they happen. You inspect your customer status, and if it is activated for the first time, you can send them flowers, or toot a horn, or do whatever needs doing. Simple, and you'd be using Shopify the way they meant you to use it.

Comment: thanks that helps. another question unrelated to this. Retreving the customer I have this link: "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Customer/902518145071", how do I use it?

Comment: You'd use the ID to get the customer at the endpoint so you could manipulate that record.

Comment: that's the thing..how? if this is the GRAPHQL url : https://mystore.myshopify.com/api/graphql for everything else, what is the url for getting user info?

Comment: Read up on GraphQL. You get one endpoint. Your call determines the data you get back. It is really not that hard to figure out. Note, you can always use the old RestAPI too.